# Is it OK to have the same content in two different answers, if it is relevant to both?

Tags: discussion

I wrote an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/124731/22611) to the question [Is tipping mandatory at Restaurants and Bars in Germany?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124708/is-tipping-mandatory-at-restaurants-and-bars-in-germany/124731#124731) that got a reasonable amount of upvotes.

I then wanted to add more reasoning to my answer and found that it is actually off-topic, because I explained how much to tip, what to say, why Germans round up, but this was not really the core of the question. The question is only about whether it is mandatory to tip in Germany.

So I opened a [new question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125123/how-much-should-i-tip-in-restaurants-in-germany/125126) so that I could post more content that would actually fit the question. I stand by that decision because it makes content easier to find because the answer matches the question.

But now I feel a dillema. On the one hand it would totally make sense to add "What to say when you tip" and "Why rounding up"-paragraphs from the original answer ot the new answer as well because they are higly relevant to anyone looking for how much to tip. On the other hand copy&pasting feels bad because it violates DRY (Do Not Repeat Yourself) and I don't want people to think that I am trying to get upvotes twice.

I could remove the content from the first question, but I already got upvotes for it, so the upvotes would not match the actual answer. (Will it still be as good as the votes suggest?) And the content is still relevant to that question.

What do you think would be the best course of action?

Comment: You can maybe quote and reference the parts which belong to the other answer to avoid content repetition and self plagiarism.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach here on StackExchange is to quote the relevant paragraphs in your second answer and provide a link to the original post. Likewise you can simply link to the previous post without quoting, as that's only mandatory for links from external sites.